# Android: Recyclerview onBindViewHolder and Snaphelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview is attached PagerSnapHelper, when i scroll Recyclerview **slow**, onBindViewHolder is called **1 time**, but when i scroll Recyclerview **fast**, onBindViewHolder is called **2 time** consecutive. How can i make Adapter calls **onBindViewHolder** only 1 time when scrolling changed?. Sorry for my english

Comment: recycler view resues its items. why you want to call it 1 time only?

Comment: Because i must call api for load data and show on view, if it call 2 time, i cannot show exactly item. When loading api done, it binded another view

Comment: Muhammad Hassaan, i editted my question, it's mean i scroll 1 time adapter calls onBind 1 time

Comment: you are calling api inside onBindViewHolder?

Comment: Yes. arraylist in adapter only contains list id of object

Comment: your method is wrong. do not call api inside bindViewHolder. instead call api in Activity or Fragment and then when you get full data array then send this full array to adapter

Comment: how about if it is too much?, example 100, i cannot call 100 times api at the same time, i think it too much.

Comment: you have to implement paging in api call and then use call back listeners inside adapter to trace current page while scrolling . and then get data for that page and then show it in recycler view

Comment: After a few days researching, i think this problem is impossible. And i solve it by custom scroll for view. Many thanks for your help, Muhammad Hassaan.

Comment: if you solved this problem. please provide me your code. we are facing same problem. as we are inflating view inside onBindViewHolder that makes processing and scrolling very slow

Comment: Oh, why you must inflate view inside onBindViewHolder instead of onCreateViewHolder? That is like listview, not recyclerview.

Comment: I am binding main view in onCreateViewHolder .. but our functionality need inflating of view inside item view of recycler view. I mean i am inflating view inside item of recycler view

Comment: Ok, i will send you my method

Comment: I put in answer

Answer (score 1):

You can see my primary code:

```
public class DetailActiveVoucherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailActiveVoucherAdapter.DetailViewHolder> {

// Constructor

// Var
private DetailViewHolder detailHolder; // i put viewholder here for using it after call api

private DataHolder<EvoucherDetailModel> dataHolderDetail;
private DataHolder<EVoucherSummary> dataHolderSummary;

public DetailActiveVoucherAdapter(...) {
    // set constructor
}

@Override
public DetailViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.row_detail_active_voucher, parent, false);
    return new DetailViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DetailViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    detailHolder = (DetailViewHolder) holder;
    currentPosition = position;
    holder.bind(); /**TODO: this is my problem */
/* problem is onBindViewHolder called 2 times successive. when i call holder.bind() i will call api, after calling api done, i show data on View
 * But second onBindViewHolder is called, and current View is view of second position and first view has nothing
 */
}

...

private void loadData(long id, final long pos) {
    DataLoader.getCashBoughtEvoucherDetail((LixiActivity) activity, new ApiCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void handleCallback(boolean isSuccess, Object object) {
            if (isSuccess) {
                detailHolder.evoucherModel = (EvoucherDetailModel) object;
                loadTotalandPriceVoucher(pos);
            } else {
                Helper.showErrorDialog((LixiActivity) activity, (String) object);
            }
        }
    }, id);
}

private void loadTotalandPriceVoucher(final long pos) {
    DataLoader.getEVoucherSummary((LixiActivity) activity, new ApiCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void handleCallback(boolean isSuccess, Object object) {
            if (onLoadingListener != null){
                onLoadingListener.onEnd();
            }
            if (isSuccess) {
                detailHolder.eVoucherSummary = (EVoucherSummary) object;
                showData((int) pos);
            }
        }
    }, detailHolder.evoucherModel.getMerchant_info().getId());
}

private void showData(int pos) {
    // show data
}

public class DetailViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    // View

// this is 2 object i get from api
    EvoucherDetailModel evoucherModel;
    EVoucherSummary eVoucherSummary;

    public DetailViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // reference view
    }

    public void bind(){
        load();
        // set event
    }
  }
 }
```

And this is my method. I don't use recyclerview, i just use a normal view: imageview, textview, ect. And let user can scroll, i custom the scrolling with onTouch event.

```
linearDrag.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (canSwipe) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        cx = getWidth() / 2 - linearDrag.getWidth() / 2;
                        privotXLeft = getWidth() / 4 - linearDrag.getWidth() / 2;
                        privotXRight = (getWidth() / 4) * 3 - linearDrag.getWidth() / 2;
                        privotXCenter = linearDrag.getX();
                        x = motionEvent.getX();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        changeX = motionEvent.getX();
                        linearDrag.setX(linearDrag.getX() + changeX - x);
                        break;
                    default:
                        // back to center
                        if ((linearDrag.getX() >= privotXCenter && linearDrag.getX() <= privotXRight) || (linearDrag.getX() >= privotXLeft && linearDrag.getX() <= privotXCenter)) {
                            linearDrag.setX(cx);
                            break;
                        }

                        // to next position
                        if (linearDrag.getX() <= privotXLeft) {
                            if (swipeNext) {
                                linearDrag.setX(-1 * getWidth());
                                if (onActionChangedListener != null) {
                                    onActionChangedListener.onChanged(NEXT);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            } else {
                                linearDrag.setX(cx);
                            }
                            break;
                        }

                        // to previous position
                        if (linearDrag.getX() >= privotXRight) {
                            if (swipePrev) {
                                linearDrag.setX(getWidth());
                                if (onActionChangedListener != null) {
                                    onActionChangedListener.onChanged(PREV);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            } else {
                                linearDrag.setX(cx);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

onActionChangedListener is interface for scroll result. After i received scroll result i will call api, reload data and update my view. I use this way because my view is pager view, at the same time it only display 1 page. If you use with normal list, it will be useless. If you have a better method please share with me.